# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument' what(): stoi error in leetcode problem

Tags: c++

I m trying a problem from leetcode about complex numbers multiplication.

However, I am facing problem in the usage of `stoi()`. The code works fine for positive complex numbers but shows error when given input like:

input : "-1+-1i", "1+-1i"

```
class Solution {
    public:
        string complexNumberMultiply(string a, string b) {
            int aplus = a.find('+');
            int bplus = b.find('+');
            int ai = a.find('i');
            int bi = b.find('i');

            int a1 = stoi(a.substr(0, aplus));
            int b1 = stoi(a.substr(aplus + 1, ai), nullptr);
            int a2 = stoi(a.substr(0, bplus), nullptr);
            int b2 = stoi(a.substr(bplus + 1, bi), nullptr);
            int aa = a1 * a2 - (b1 * b2);
            int ab = a1 * b2 + a2 * b1;
            string res = to_string(aa) + "+" + to_string(ab) + "i";
            return res;
        }
};
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please also add the error that you're getting.

Comment: Please, provide your input as well. Stoi will throw this exception if the input string doesn't start with digit / whitespace character sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you made a mistake.

For `a2` and `b2` you used `a.substr()` instead of `b.substr()`.

I tested with you example and it returned -2+0i as result.

Comment: It works fine for positive numbers. The error is seen only for the test cases like -1+-1i.

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Thanks for helping me out.